# Flipping vertically a raw image in Java

Tags: java, graphics, image-processing, awt

I need to flip in Java a raw image that has her rows inverted. By inverted I mean, the first row of the image is stored at the end of a file.

I managed to achive what I want by reordering the image rows using an auxiliar buffer. I included my code below.

I think this can be optimized by translating the coordinates, avoiding the memory copy. I tried to implement a DataBuffer that would invert the rows, but the raster I'm using requires a DataBufferByte (a final class).

Does anyone knows a more optimized way of doing what I want?

Thank you

```
...
int w = 640;
int h = 480;
byte[] flippedData = new byte[640*480*4];
int scanLineLength = w*4;
for(int i=0;i!=h; ++i) {
  System.arraycopy(originalData, scanLineLength*i, flippedData, scanLineLength*(h-i)-scanLineLength, scanLineLength);
}

DataBuffer db = new DataBufferByte(flippedData,flippedData.length);
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(db, w, h, scanLineLength, 4, new int[]{2,1,0}, new Point(0,0));
ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(cs, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, false, null);
ImageIO.write(img, "JPEG", new File("out.jpg"));
```

Comment: what is your reason for hardcoding a pixel encoding and a ColorSpace? If you do a *GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(). getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration(). createCompatibleImage(...)* you'll have a pixel encoding that is best suited to the platform your program is running on.

Comment: I your code you are passing a DataBuffer variable to the Raster, not a DataBufferByte.

Comment: @Webinator: because I don't want to show the image on screen

Comment: @codymanix: Nope. I'm passing a DataBufferByte

Answer (score 4):

Use [`java.awt.AffineTransform`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html):

> Affine transformations can be constructed using sequences of translations, scales, flips, rotations, and shears.

See [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23667&seqNum=11) and [this](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/affinetransform.html) to see how is flipping implemented using `AffineTransform`